# Google Tag Manager Server-Side gtm.js returns 404

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I created a new Server-side GTM Container, set up Google App Engine, added a GTM Client, and have everything deployed. However, when I check the `gtm.js` for the container the file returns a 404.

So I created the the App Engine instance using the automatic configuration and it returns `ok` for the `/healthy` path.

The GTM container is published and has an active tag and trigger. Here is a screenshot of the GTM Client.
[image]

I have this snippet added to my site:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://gtm-p3vlp32-ndhiz.uc.r.appspot.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-P3VLP32');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Then I get this error in the network tab. Did I miss a step to get the `gtm.js` file to be returned?

[image]

Comment: Look like you use server GTM ID you need to use web one here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you haven't set up the domain to your GTM Server side. In the Admin tab, on container settings, go to "Server Container URL" and put your domain where your GTM Server Side is located.